# Is 夢を見せる the same as 夢を見る?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

I see both 夢を見せる and 夢を見る spoken by Japanese. Do they have the completely same meaning?

== Update ==

I'm referring to a 夢を見せて which is from the lyrics of a song called [おはよう。](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-12377.html)

The full version is a bit long. Here is [the shorter version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1GJfw0xu8A), and the 夢を見せて is in the second line. The context is:

また“おはよう”って言って
また夢を見せて
今日も元気で過ごせたらイイよね

Comment: 見せる: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B

Comment: @broccoliforest I know its meaning. But I see both phrases used for saying "to dream" so I have the question.

Comment: Could you provide some context?

Comment: @broccoliforest I had updated the question and provided context.

Comment: Why do you think that 夢を見せる means "to dream" rather than the literal "to show [someone] a dream"?

Comment: 夢を見せる clearly means 'give (someone) a dream'; why would think otherwise?

Comment: Well... I was actually not sure about that myself. I made that conclusion because I have seen two translations of that line be made as "I fall into a dream" and "have a dream again" so I thought that phrase probably means "to dream", too. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

夢を見る means "dream" as a verb, or see a dream, as in "ハーバードに入るという夢を見る - dream of entering Harvard University," and "昨晩、母の夢を見た - I had a dream of my mother last night."

夢を見せる means to give a dream, as in "子供たちに明るい日本の将来の夢を見せる - give a dream of the bright future of Japan to children."

また夢を見せて can be translated as "Let me see (that wonderful) dream once more."

Comment: Can I ask you a question? I think the meaning of 夢を見させる and 夢を見せる are different. How do また夢を見させて translate into English? It is "Let me see a dream once more" , isn't it?

Comment: @Yuichi Tam. At my age , I don't like to argue laborious fine points. To me,  夢を見させる and 夢を見せる are both saying the same thing, though 夢を見させて sounds gamatically correct than 夢を見せて.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ask you for my study of English.

Answer (score 0):

They are different verbs. 見せる is "to show" while 見る is "to see".

> 夢【ゆめ】を見せる【みせる】 to show a dream
>   夢【ゆめ】を見る【みる】 to look at/see a dream